# String.to_atom resulting in and atom with double quotes buried in it

Tags: elixir

I've got this code where I using a pair of lists to get a map with one list being the keys and the other list being the values. Pretty straight forward code:

```
defp create_data_map(columns, row) do
  Enum.zip(columns, row)
  |> Enum.into(%{}, fn {k, v} ->
    {String.to_atom(k), v}
  end)
end
```

I'm getting these lists from a csv file where columns is the first line, which is the list of headers, and the second line is any one of the lines after that. Here is what the header looks like:

```
["action", "source_application", "partner_name", "detail", "college_name",
 "ipeds_id", "deleted", "deleted_at", "athlete_id", "athlete_email",
 "athlete_first_name", "athlete_last_name", "athlete_sport_id",
 "athlete_sport_name", "pass_uuid", "coach_id", "coach_id", 
 "coach_email",
 "coach_first_name", "coach_last_name", "coach_position", "coach_sport_id",
 "coach_sport_name", "occurred_at"]
```

For some reason, the 'action' key, after calling String.to_atom/1 ends up being `:"action"`. None of the other keys have that issue. They are all correctly formed atoms.

I don't see what's different about that action key from the other keys, aside from the fact that it's at the start of the list.

Comment: I can't reproduce this with `[..your list..] |> Enum.map(&String.to_atom/1)`. Can you post the complete code including the call to `create_data_map` which reproduces the behavior you're seeing?

Comment: There is some stuff I have to strip out before I can post. I want to make sure I get the same bad result after I do that. Bottom line, it will take me a bit to get the better code example here. thanks!

Comment: My guess is that you have some weird character somewhere in the first string. Maybe a zero-width space or a letter is not ASCII but looks like it.

Comment: bingo. There is a <feff> at the start of the file. sheesh.

Comment: That's a byte order mark (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark). If you want it to be stripped you can pass :trim_bom as mode param in File.stream! more info: https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/File.html#stream!/3

Answer (score 1):

When `inspect/1` renders your atom as `:"hello world"`, the name of the atom contains characters like whitespace, dots or uppercase letters.

See how you would not be able to reference the above atom as `:hello world`, because it would interpret `world` as a variable.

They are still valid atoms, though it might be harder to use them in your code.

Comment: yep. but the one I'm seeing is a single word. It turns out there was a hidden character at the front of the file. See Mark Meeus' comment above. Thanks for the answer!

Answer (score 1):

There are 3 different ways an `Atom` can appear when converted using `String.to_atom()`

1. :"Atom-" or :"atom-"
2. :Atom or :atom
3. Atom

All the 3 above are atoms. The only difference in them is the way the strings are formatted.

1. First one is obtained for any usual string that also contains special characters like #$%-  ...

    `iex> "Atom-" |> String.to_atom`
   `:"Atom-"`
2. Then similar to how `functions` names are subtly formatted in elixir. i.e. the string starts with an alphabet and the remaining string can only contain alphabets, numbers, or the three special characters _!@ . 

   `iex> "Atom" |> String.to_atom`
   `:Atom`
3. Third again in the same way as `Modules` are named subtly in Elixir. Since internally, module names are just atoms as well. The String should start with `Elixir.` followed by a capital letter and can contain only alphabets. 

   `iex> "Elixir.Atom" |> String.to_atom`
   `Atom​​​`

---

[Module Names: Elixir, Erlang, and Atoms](https://www.safaribooksonline.com/library/view/programming-elixir/9781680500530/f_0060.html)

[Understanding Aliases](https://rokobasilisk.gitbooks.io/elixir-getting-started/content/alias,_require_and_import/understanding_aliases.html)